# Powershell - DataViewGrid - Column Autosize

Tags: powershell, datagrid, autosize

I am a complete novice when it comes to .NET and powershell and was wondering if you guys could assist. I am generating a Data Grid from a .CSV on a form and would like the grid to auto size columns accordingly. Also if I could lock the columns/rows from user adjustment that would be amazing.

```
Clear-Host
Function Populate-CycleCountDataGrid {
  $InventoryListArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $Script:InventoryList = @(Import-CSV C:\File.csv | Write-Output)
  $InventoryListArray.AddRange($Script:InventoryList)
  $CycleCountDataGrid.DataSource = $InventoryListArray
}

Function GenerateForm {
  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

  $RefreshButton_Click = {
    Populate-CycleCountDataGrid
  }

    # Form Setup
    #*******************************************************************************************\
    $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection= { $objForm.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState }

    $objForm.Text = "CycleCount"
    $objForm.Name = "CycleCount"
    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,480)
    $objForm.StartPosition = 0
    $objForm.AutoSize = $False
    $objForm.MinimizeBox = $False
    $objForm.MaximizeBox = $False
    $objForm.WindowState = "Normal"

    # DataGrid
    #*******************************************************************************************\
    $CycleCountDataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
    $CycleCountDataGrid.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(592,400)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.AutoSize = $False
    $CycleCountDataGrid.AllowSorting = $False
    $CycleCountDataGrid.ReadOnly = $True
    $CycleCountDataGrid.CaptionText = "Inventory List"
    $CycleCountDataGrid.HeaderFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",8.25,1,3,0)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.HeaderForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",8.25,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,160,250)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.AlternatingBackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,133,194,255)
    $CycleCountDataGrid.Name = "CycleCountDataGrid"
    $CycleCountDataGrid.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $objForm.Controls.Add($CycleCountDataGrid)
    #*******************************************************************************************/

    # Refresh Button
    #*******************************************************************************************\
    $RefreshButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $RefreshButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,400)
    $RefreshButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(590,45)
    $RefreshButton.Name = "RefreshButton"
    $RefreshButton.Text = "Refresh"
    $RefreshButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $RefreshButton.add_Click($RefreshButton_Click)
    $RefreshButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $objForm.Controls.Add($RefreshButton)
    #*******************************************************************************************/

    $objForm.Topmost = $True
    $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
    $objForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
    $objForm.MaximizeBox = $False
    $objForm.Add_FormClosing([System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler]{
        if ($objForm.DialogResult -eq "Cancel") {}
    })

    $InitialFormWindowState = $objForm.WindowState
    $objForm.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
    $objForm.ShowDialog()
    #*******************************************************************************************/
}
GenerateForm
```

Comment: Hey Mitul,

I Don't understand really, is there any way you could provide an example with the script above?

Comment: http://odetocode.com/articles/59.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code:

```
$CycleCountDataGrid.Columns | Foreach-Object{
    $_.AutoSizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::AllCells
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your control to a system.windows.forms.datagridview rather than just a datagrid.  Then you have access to `$CycleCountDataGrid.columns`

Each column has a width property.  The answer above will try to autosize each column but you could specify each one if you like.

```
$CycleCountDatarid.columns[0].width = 200
```

100 is the default

Answer (score 0):

The secret to Autosizing a Windows.Forms.Datagrid is that it has a private method 'ColAutoResize' you can invoke with Reflection:

```
Function AutoResizeColumns([System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid] $dg1){ 
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] $F = 'static','nonpublic','instance' 
    $ColAutoResizeMethod = $dg1.GetType().GetMethod('ColAutoResize', $F) 
    If($ColAutoResizeMethod) { 
        For ([int]$i = $dg1.FirstVisibleColumn; $i -lt $dg1.VisibleColumnCount; $i++){
            $ColAutoResizeMethod.Invoke($dg1, $i) | Out-Null 
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that function, you can add it to the DataGrid's VisibleChanged and DataSourceChanged events so drawing and refreshing the DataGrid will invoke AutoResizeColumns:

```
$objForm.Controls["CycleCountDataGrid"].add_DatasourceChanged({ AutoResizeColumns $objForm.Controls["CycleCountDataGrid"] } )
$objForm.Controls["CycleCountDataGrid"].add_VisibleChanged({ AutoResizeColumns $objForm.Controls["CycleCountDataGrid"] } )
$objForm.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but it's working for me.